# What's the proper way to understand which type of ModelState validation error it is?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, modelstate

I am trying to understand whether the error is with JSON format (missing comma and whatnot), or a missing required field (model validation), and return to the user one of the defined custom errors without showing the error message that ModelState has.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
{
   var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors);
}
```

I've tried looking for exceptions for these errors

```
var jsonErrors = errors.Where(e => e.Exception is JsonException).ToList();
```

However `Exception` property is always `null`. How come?
The only way right now it seems to have some logic filtering on `ErrorMessage` property, which just seems strange.

Comment: "return to the user one of the defined custom errors" Do you want to [create custom validation attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#custom-attributes) ?

Comment: My question is not necessarily about the way to implement validation or how to return an error, rather about how to understand that the error in the `ModelState` (or a `context`, since I can access it too) is because the JSON payload was missing a comma, or a bracket, etc.

Answer (score 0):

ModelState.IsValid is checking for validation errors. Exception is null because these are validation errors, not the exceptions thrown during json deserialization.

```
try
{
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(jsonString);
}
catch (JsonException ex)
{
    // Handle JSON parsing errors here
}
```

You can catch Json Exceptions in the code above, when you were in deserialization step.

Answer (score 0):

When the model supplied is invalid (for example missing field) you can easily check it as shown below:

```
var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).ToArray();
var errorMesages = errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).ToArray();
```

[image]

When it comes to handling JSON body exceptions, if you'd inspect post requests made by an ASP.NET you'd see (as per my example)

> Person.FirstName=fasdfsdgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg&Person.LastName=asdfasdfasdfasfasdfasfa&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8O2s-bQ2bZROn_Jr2RHoSWoVCXk6TQzUjVw_1jD36-5-Q02ARXTUpD0I_2O2Gk0gU3mNysSL2C75gndZ5FCWldmLjB3Bw_JDPM0GLRxqIRjryZ0l7lad6H8KLSWD_wZWyNLPsvq_MGd6d_5Fix19EU4

So, body format in ASP.NET pages, is handled internally, and you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: I don't need to worry about that. I just want to provide the response to the client, that the JSON was incorrectly formatted.

Comment: @okThen But you are not dealing with any JSN here, so such response does not makes much sense.

Comment: not sure what you mean. If I can find an error that JSON was incorrectly formatted, means it's a valid response.